# How to structure a has_many association with a dynamic scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, associations

I have a users table in my db. A user can be either of type 'admin' or 'manager'.

Given the models and schema below, I would like that for each instance of 'manager' user, an 'admin' user could select one, some or all the locations of the tenant that the manager belongs to in order to select which locations the manager can have control over.

### My models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tenant
```

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :locations, dependent: :destroy
```

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tenant, inverse_of: :locations
```

## I've tried two paths

**First**, trying to establish a scoped has_many association between the User and the Location models. However, I can't wrap my head around structuring this scope so that an 'admin' user could select which locations the 'manager' users can control.

**Second**, setting up a controlled_locations attribute in the users table. Then I set up some code so that an 'admin' user can select which locations a 'manager' can control, populating its 'controlled_locations' attribute. However, what gets saved in the database (inside the controlled_locations array) is strings instead of instances of locations.

### Here's the code that I tried for the second path:

### The migration

```
def change
  add_column :users, :controlled_locations, :string, array: true, default: []
end
```

### In the view

```
= f.input :controlled_locations, label: 'Select', collection: @tenant_locations, include_blank: "Anything", wrapper_html: { class: 'form-group' }, as: :check_boxes, include_hidden: false, input_html: {multiple: true}
```

### In the users controller (inside the update method)

```
if params["user"]["controlled_locations"]
  params["user"]["controlled_locations"].each do |l|
    resource.controlled_locations << Location.find(l.to_i)
  end
  resource.save!
end
```

## What I expect

First of all, I'm not quite sure the second path that I tried is a good approach (storing arrays in the db). So my best choice would be to set up a scoped association if it's possible.

*In case the second path is feasible, what I would like to get is something like this. Let's say that logging in an Admin, I selected that the user with ID 1 (a manager) can control one location (Boston Stadium):*

```
user = User.find(1)
user.controlled_locations = [#<Location id: 55, name: "Boston Stadium", created_at: "2018-10-03 12:45:58", updated_at: "2018-10-03 12:45:58", tenant_id: 5>]
```

*Instead, what I get after trying is this:*

```
user = User.find(1)
user.controlled_locations = ["#<Location:0x007fd2be0717a8>"]
```

Instead of instances of locations, what gets saved in the array is just plain strings.

Comment: You´re correct in that storing arrays in the DB is not a very good solution. It does not work with ActiveRecord associations and is poor DB design. A better idea is to actually setup a join table between users and locations which is how relational databases are meant to be used.

Comment: You are right, I could simply associate users and locations, adding 'has_many :locations, through: :tenant' to the User model. However, that would associate ALL the locations to the user, which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is create a join model which describes the relation between users and locations and set it up as a many to many association. This kind of authorization is usually done with a system of roles - take a look at the [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) gem if you want an example.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code is missing the `locations` association in the `Tenant` class.

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :locations
```

Let's say the variable `manager` has a `User` record.  Then the locations it can control are:

```
manager.tenant.locations
```

If you want, you can shorten this with a delegate statement.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tenant
  delegate :locations, to: :tenant
```

then you can call this with

```
manager.locations
```

Comment: Thanks Marlin, I had forgotten the 'locations' association in the Tenant model. I've edited the question accordingly.

Your solution would associate ALL the locations of a certain tenant to the user, which is not what I'm trying to achieve. I'd like to associate only some of them.

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern used for authorization is roles:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles

  def add_role(name, location)
    self.roles << Role.find_or_create_by(name: name, location: location)
  end

  def has_role?(name, location)
    self.roles.exists?(name: name, location: location)
  end
end

# rails g model role name:string
# make sure you add a unique index on name and location
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :location_id
end

# rails g model user_role user:references role:references
# make sure you add a unique compound index on role_id and user_id
class UserRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :role_id
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
  has_many :users, through: :roles
end
```

By making the system a bit more generic than say a controlled_locations association you can re-use it for different cases.

> Let's say that logging in an Admin, I selected that the user with ID 1
>   (a manager) can control one location (Boston Stadium)

```
User.find(1)
    .add_role(:manager, Location.find_by(name: "Boston Stadium"))
```

In actual MVC terms you can do this by setting up roles as a nested resource that can be CRUD'ed just like any other resource. Editing multiple roles in a single form can be done with [`accepts_nested_attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) or AJAX.

If you want to scope a query by the presence of a role then join the roles and user roles table:

```
Location.joins(roles: :user_roles)
        .where(roles: { name: :manager })
        .where(user_roles: { user_id: 1 })
```

To authenticate a single resource you would do:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protected 
  def deny_access
    redirect_to "your/sign_in/path", error: 'You are not authorized.'
  end
end

class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def update
    @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
    deny_access and return unless current_user.has_role?(:manger, @location)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Instead of rolling your own authorization system though I would consider using [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) and [pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit).